# mkdir permission denied

Tags: python, unix, permissions, mkdir

I'm trying to make this directory `/var/machine/hi'` by running this in Python:

```
os.mkdir("/var/machine/hi")
```

However, I'm getting a

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/machine/hi'
```

I have tried the following:
    `chmod 777 /var/machine` and `chmod 777 /var`

The owners for `/var` is `root` `wheel`

The owners for `/var/machine` is `root` `wheel`

How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: Can you give some more information? Output of `ls -l /var/machine`? What is the user that starts the script?

Comment: You tried running your script as `sudo`?

Comment: yes, the script works when I run it with sudo, however is there an alternative solution?

Comment: No, the owner of the directory in which you are trying to create the directory is `root`, and hence, you either run as `root`, or as `sudo`

Comment: If `/var/machine` has `775` rights, and the group is `wheel` he can run the script with any user that has the group `wheel` too and it should work.

Comment: hey sorry, I made a mistake, turns out my chmod 777 /var/machine didn't work. I've properly given it 775 and now it works w/o having to run sudo. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: remove the quote/`'` after `hi` in the first line

Comment: if you want `777` try `chmod -R /var/machine` `-R` stands for recursive

Comment: If this is ubuntu... be concerned about app armor.

but definitely get an strace of the user trying to do a mkdir from bash.  

ie:  strace -o mkdir.log mkdir -p /var/machine/hi

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried using os.system with a sudo command on the operation only?

```
os.system("sudo mkdir /var/machine/hi")
```

Comment: Seems that if I run this under Python console, after entering the password the program cannot terminate and freezes. The password was correct.

Answer (score 0):

> The owners for /var is root wheel
>
> The owners for /var/machine is root wheel

The owner of the directory in which you are trying to create the directory is `root`, and hence, you will either have to run as `root`, or as `sudo`.

Alternatively, you can change the directory user ownership using

```
sudo chown popcorn:wheel /var/machine
```

but this assumes user popcorn is added in `wheel`